# jQuery Title tag

Tags: jquery

How find a DOM elements which has Title tags?

```
<span class="t-filename" title="!!!!.txt">!!!!.txt</span>
```

jQuery to find DOM element

```
$(".t-filename ***What I should put here***")
```

Answer (score 5):

1) for `title` having `!!!!.txt`

```
$(".t-filename[title='!!!!.txt']")
```

2) for all elements with class `t-filename` with ***any*** `title`

```
$(".t-filename[title]")
```

3) for `title` ends with .txt

```
$(".t-filename[title$='.txt']")
```

---

For More Info, [See Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$('.t-filename[title]');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is enough to find all elements with title tag

```
$('[title]')
```

And this to find span with title tag :)

```
$('span[title]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Find elements with the class specified and the title attribute specified:

```
$('.t-filename[title="!!!!.txt"]')
```

Find elements with the class specified and that contain the text specified:

```
$('.t-filename:contains("!!!!.txt")')
```

To find all elements with the specified class and that has **any** title attribute:

```
$('.t-filename[title]')
```

Comment: Question was to find elements that have title tags, not for specific data inside that or if it contains any

Comment: The question wasn't too clear. The !!!! sort of implied -- to me -- that the goal was to search for specific title tag where the !!!! was a specific pattern being searched. Thanks for pointing that out. Answer updated.